# iperf3 shows that udp with set bandwidth is still x2 slower than tcp

Tags: networking, download-speed, tcp-ip

I opened iperf3 server on host 192.168.1.105:

```
iperf3 -sV
```

Then client on TCP on same host:

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.105 -4b 10G -P 2 -n 10G -w 1M
```

Results are:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-5.87   sec  5.00 GBytes  7.32 Gbits/sec    2             sender
[  4]   0.00-5.87   sec  5.00 GBytes  7.31 Gbits/sec                  receiver
[  6]   0.00-5.87   sec  5.00 GBytes  7.31 Gbits/sec    6             sender
[  6]   0.00-5.87   sec  4.99 GBytes  7.30 Gbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-5.87   sec  10.0 GBytes  14.6 Gbits/sec    8             sender
[SUM]   0.00-5.87   sec  9.99 GBytes  14.6 Gbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Then udp client

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.105 -u4b 10G -P 2 -n 10G -w 1M
```

and results

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-106.05 sec  48.8 GBytes  3.96 Gbits/sec  0.001 ms  181932/6400000 (2.8%)
[  4] Sent 6400000 datagrams
[  6]   0.00-106.05 sec  48.8 GBytes  3.96 Gbits/sec  0.002 ms  182081/6400000 (2.8%)
[  6] Sent 6400000 datagrams
[SUM]   0.00-106.05 sec  97.7 GBytes  7.91 Gbits/sec  0.002 ms  364013/12800000 (2.8%)
```

Where comes the difference?

The same ratio happens when I run client on laptop with 1Gbps network interface.

From laptop client, for udp I have speed 250Mbits/sec (task manager shows load ~ 25% on network interface) from linux subsystem. For tcp speed is 500Mbits/sec...

Comment: interesting. I get 932 Mbits/sec TCP and 959 Mbits/sec UDP between two computers. On the same computer for server and client I get 11.9 Gbits/sec UDP (CPU limited) and 19.7 Gbits/sec TCP.

Comment: Should udp would not be faster, somehow I remember that some post stated tcp is 50% faster than udp. How its possible?

Comment: The computer to computer case is gigabit channel limited and the computer to itself case is CPU limited for UDP.

Comment: Then cpu utilisation should go to 1 or it will nrver happen??

Comment: I do not know. I am just giving results for my test case.